# Stop every JS events in the loaded web page after page load (via browser console)

Tags: javascript, console.log

JS timeouts and events tend to load and poll resources after loading of the web page making inspecting the console quite difficult. Is there a way to prevent every JS events using any commands that can be injected via the console?

Comment: Disable it at some point in the execution: http://i.imgur.com/TuwpOG6.png Or like this: http://i.imgur.com/Arjlswv.png

Comment: what type of events you want to stop? click ones?

Comment: Are you asking for `console.log = function noop(){}`?

Comment: I am looking to stop all the interval based polling activities the pages does in an typical ajax page. Requests keeps buzzing in the network console that it is virtually impossible to click on something and look at the parameters since a load of requests keeps pouring in.